# Solve the differential equation for y(t) in terms of x(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Consider the following differential equation:
$$  
(t+1)y'(t) + y(t) = x'(t) + x(t) \quad (t > 0)
$$
With initial conditions
$$
y(0) = 0 \quad x(0) = 0
$$

Solve for $y(t)$ in terms of $x(t)$.

Also, (although I can probably figure out this part on my own) - is the system linear? Causal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define $\tilde y(t)=(t+1) y(t)$. Then 
$$
\tilde y^\prime =x^\prime +x
$$
Then 
$$
\tilde y(t)=x(t)+\int_0^t x(t) dt+C
$$
and 
$$
y(t)=(x(t)+\int_0^t x(t) dt+C)/(t+1)
$$
From initial condition $C=0$.